# Como passar dados de activity para fragment

Tags: android, android-fragment, android-activity

Eu já vi uns posts sobre mas eu não consegui entender como passar uma string de uma `activity` para um `fragment`

Eu tenho a main:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener, 
SearchView.OnQueryTextListener {

private Fragment currentFragment;
private home fragment1 = new home();
private clientes fragment2 = new clientes();
private contas_pagar fragment3 = new contas_pagar();
private contas fragment4 = new contas();
String t = "teste";


private BottomViewPagerAdapter bottomViewPagerAdapter;
private ArrayList<AHBottomNavigationItem> bottomNavigationItems = new 
ArrayList<>();

// UI
private AHBottomNavigationViewPager viewPagerBottom;
private AHBottomNavigation bottomNavigation;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    clientes apresentacaofragment = new clientes();
    // Declarando o valor
    Bundle bundlemain = new Bundle();
    bundlemain.putString("TESTE1", "olá");
    // Passando os dados
    apresentacaofragment.setArguments(bundlemain);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, 
R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) 
findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

    initUI();
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_search, menu);
    MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) 
MenuItemCompat.getActionView(searchItem);
    // Configure the search info and add any event listeners

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {
        // Handle the camera action
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}

private void initUI() {

    bottomNavigation = (AHBottomNavigation) 
findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation);
    viewPagerBottom = (AHBottomNavigationViewPager) 
findViewById(R.id.view_pager_bottom);

    //Aqui onde é adicionado os fragments no bottom
    viewPagerBottom.setOffscreenPageLimit(2);
    bottomViewPagerAdapter = new 
BottomViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    bottomViewPagerAdapter.add(fragment1);
    bottomViewPagerAdapter.add(fragment2);
    bottomViewPagerAdapter.add(fragment3);
    bottomViewPagerAdapter.add(fragment4);
    viewPagerBottom.setAdapter(bottomViewPagerAdapter);

    currentFragment = bottomViewPagerAdapter.getCurrentFragment();


    AHBottomNavigationItem item1 = new AHBottomNavigationItem("Home", 
R.drawable.ic_home_black_24dp);
    AHBottomNavigationItem item2 = new AHBottomNavigationItem("Clientes", 
R.drawable.clientes);
    AHBottomNavigationItem item3 = new AHBottomNavigationItem("Contas", 
R.drawable.pagar);
    AHBottomNavigationItem item4 = new AHBottomNavigationItem("Histórico", 
R.drawable.contas);

    bottomNavigationItems.add(item1);
    bottomNavigationItems.add(item2);
    bottomNavigationItems.add(item3);
    bottomNavigationItems.add(item4);

    bottomNavigation.addItems(bottomNavigationItems);


    bottomNavigation.setAccentColor(Color.parseColor("#F63D2B"));
    bottomNavigation.setInactiveColor(Color.parseColor("#747474"));
    bottomNavigation.setCurrentItem(0);

    bottomNavigation.setNotification("Vencida", 2);

    bottomNavigation.findViewById(R.id.textView18);


    bottomNavigation.setOnTabSelectedListener(new 
AHBottomNavigation.OnTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTabSelected(int position, boolean wasSelected) {

            if (currentFragment == null) {
                currentFragment = 
bottomViewPagerAdapter.getCurrentFragment();
            }


            if (currentFragment != null) {
                if (currentFragment instanceof home) {

                    fragment1.willBeHidden();

                } else if (currentFragment instanceof clientes) {

                    fragment2.willBeHidden();

                } else if (currentFragment instanceof contas_pagar) {

                    fragment3.willBeHidden();

                } else if (currentFragment instanceof contas){

                    fragment4.willBeHidden();

                }
            }

            //Aqui é onde é setado qual o fragment atual
            //Em seguida é pego o fragment atual e feito o fade dependendo 
 de qual instancia for
            viewPagerBottom.setCurrentItem(position, false);
            currentFragment = bottomViewPagerAdapter.getCurrentFragment();

            if (currentFragment instanceof home) {

                fragment1.willBeDisplayed();

            } else if (currentFragment instanceof clientes) {

                fragment2.willBeDisplayed();

            } else if (currentFragment instanceof contas_pagar) {

                fragment3.willBeDisplayed();

            } else if (currentFragment instanceof  contas){

                fragment4.willBeDisplayed();

            }

            if (position == 0) {

            }

            return true;
        }
    });

    bottomNavigation.setOnNavigationPositionListener(new 
AHBottomNavigation.OnNavigationPositionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPositionChange(int y) {
            Log.d("DemoActivity", "BottomNavigation Position: " + y);
        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
    return false;
}
}
```

tentei passar os dados assim:

```
    clientes apresentacaofragment = new clientes();
    // Declarando o valor
    Bundle bundlemain = new Bundle();
    bundlemain.putString("TESTE1", "olá");
    // Passando os dados
    apresentacaofragment.setArguments(bundlemain);
```

E receber assim na fragment

```
Bundle dados = getArguments();
    String valor = dados.getString("TESTE1");
```

codigo do fragment:

```
public class clientes extends Fragment {

private FrameLayout fragmentContainer;
private FloatingActionButton addCli, refresh;
private ListView lista;
public ProgressBar progressBar;
String url = "";
String parametros = "";

String[] array = new String[8];
String[] nome = {};
String[] telefone = {};
String[] celular = {};
String[] renda = {};
String[] limite = {};
String[] status = {};
String[] bandeira = {};
String[] id2 = {};
String select, nome2, telefone2, celular2, renda2, limite2, status2, 
bandeira2, texto;
String id123;
String teste;

 @Nullable
 @Override
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, 
 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_clientes, container, 
 false);

    Bundle dados = getArguments();
    String valor = dados.getString("TESTE1");

    setHasOptionsMenu(true);

    fragmentContainer = (FrameLayout) 
 view.findViewById(R.id.fragment_container_1);
    addCli = (FloatingActionButton) 
view.findViewById(R.id.floatingActionButton);
    refresh = (FloatingActionButton) view.findViewById(R.id.refresh);
    progressBar = (ProgressBar) view.findViewById(R.id.login_progress);
    TextView teste2 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView18);

    Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), valor, 
 Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


    Intent intent = getActivity().getIntent();
    id123 = intent.getStringExtra("id");

    lista = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.pagar);

    addCli.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), new_cliente.class);
            intent.putExtra("id123", id123);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    refresh.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            listartodos();
        }
    });

    listartodos();
    return view;
}
```

BottomViewPagerAdapter:

```
public class BottomViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

private ArrayList<Fragment> fragments = new ArrayList<>();
private Fragment currentFragment;

public BottomViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
}

public void add(Fragment frag) {
    this.fragments.add(frag);

}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    return fragments.get(position);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return fragments.size();
}

@Override
public void setPrimaryItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) 
{
    if (getCurrentFragment() != object) {
        currentFragment = ((Fragment) object);
    }
    super.setPrimaryItem(container, position, object);
}

/**
 * Get the current fragment
 */
public Fragment getCurrentFragment() {
    return currentFragment;
}
}
```

logcat:

> 02-09 13:38:54.015 11299-11299/insidetechnology.studio.ostdor.forbusiness E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                            Process: insidetechnology.studio.ostdor.forbusiness, PID: 11299
>                                                                                           java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.os.Bundle.getString(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
>                                                                                               at insidetechnology.studio.ostdor.forbusiness.home.onCreateView(home.java:61)
>                                                                                                at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2248)
>                                                                                               at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1340)
>                                                                                                at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1569)
>                                                                                               at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1636)
>                                                                                                at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:758)
>                                                                                                at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2415)
>                                                                                              at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2201)
>                                                                                                at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.optimizeAndExecuteOps(FragmentManager.java:2155)
>                                                                                                at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execSingleAction(FragmentManager.java:2034)
>                                                                                               at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitNowAllowingStateLoss(BackStackRecord.java:626)
>                                                                                               at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:143)
>                                                                                               at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1268)
>                                                                                              at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1116)
>                                                                                                at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1642)
>                                                                                              at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20084)
>                                                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6282)
>                                                                                                at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasureChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:714)
>                                                                                               at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasure(CoordinatorLayout.java:786)
>                                                                                              at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20084)
>                                                                                                at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onMeasure(DrawerLayout.java:1081)
>                                                                                               at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20084)
>                                                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6282)
>                                                                                                at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:214)
>                                                                                               at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:139)
>                                                                                               at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20084)
>                                                                                               at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6282)
>                                                                                                at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1705)
>                                                                                               at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:797)
>                                                                                                at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:657)
>                                                                                             at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20084)
>                                                                                              at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6282)
>                                                                                               at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:214)
>                                                                                               at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20084)
>                                                                                               at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6282)
>                                                                                                at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1705)
>                                                                                              at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:797)
>                                                                                                at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:657)
>                                                                                               at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20084)
>                                                                                               at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6282)
>                                                                                              at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:214)
>                                                                                               at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onMeasure(DecorView.java:714)
>                                                                                               at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20084)
>                                                                                               at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2627)
>                                                                                               at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1577)
>                                                                                          at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1846)
>                                                                                              at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1462)
>                                                                                               at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6960)
>                                                                                             at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:907)
>                                                                                                at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:709)
>                                                                                                at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:644)
>                                                                                                  at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:893)
>   02-09 13:38:54.016 11299-11299/insidetechnology.studio.ostdor.forbusiness E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:836)
>                                                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
>                                                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:208)
>                                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6267)
>                                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1063)
>                                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:924)

Alguém sabe como passa a string entre a activity e o fragment?

Por favor não marquem como duplicada pois a outra pergunta similar a essa não explica praticamente nada.

Comment: O que é que você não entendeu? Em quê o seu código não funciona?

Comment: Do jeito que mostrei que fiz, não funciona, simplesmente quando abro o app para de funcionar

Comment: Se pára de funcionar é porque deu erro. Veja na aba **logcat** qual é ele e coloque-o na pergunta.

Comment: Como vejo essa aba? Tenho que abrir pelo emulador?

Comment: @ramaral pronto, adicionei

Comment: O erro está no arquivo/fragmento `home.java`

Comment: @ValdeirPsr e como resolvo? N teria outro método de passar dados entre activity e fragments não? Se sim, você poderia me mostrar algo?

Comment: @WotonSampaio o jeito que você está fazendo não está errado, mas o erro é porque você não está passando o `Bundle` para o fragmento `home`. Qual o código do fragmento `home`. No método `getItem` do `BottomViewPagerAdapter` é necessário setar os argumentos. Código de exemplo https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentPagerAdapter.html

Comment: @ValdeirPsr o código do fragmento eu incluí na pergunto, vou dar uma olhada no seu exemplo aí.